# How can I fix this mesh rotation issue?

Tags: rigging

I have been crafting a 3D model of Mickey Mouse. I joined all of the meshes together and added armature. Everything seems to be correct, but when i rotate the head, the eyes and tongue don't rotate. Is there something I'm missing or something I'm doing wrong?

[image: Ref A]

[image: Ref B]

Comment: could you please provide the .blend file to help you?

Comment: you took a picture of your screen? oh boy....

Comment: You can take a screen shot using the printscreen button. To access your screenshot, just press ctrl V in paint.

Comment: @X-27 maybe they were asking it on the phone and making a photo is easier

Comment: I don't know... the Stack Exchange app is an absolute pain, and they obviously were running Blender on either a desktop or laptop, so they easily could have used the site.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign weights to meshes you want to move with a bone.

(After selecting your mesh and armature and parenting using automatic weights)

- Select your armature and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to enter
  *pose mode*
- Select your mesh and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and then you can assign weights to parts to want to move with the bone

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the most likely cause is that you failed to parent the eyes and the tongue to the head correctly.

Comment: but they are joined together into one mesh

Comment: i think you didn't assign weights to the eyes and tongue to the head bone